# "Free▼" is being split into two words in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, special-characters, text-alignment

I have a div with `text-align: justify` which contains a few words spread out to fill the div, one of which is "Free▼". On Mozilla, "Free▼" is printed as one word, but on Chrome, it is separated into two different words, as illustrated in this fiddle: ( http://jsfiddle.net/806hjj7a/ ).

Does anyone know how I can make strings containing special characters print as one word?

```
<div class="justify">
  Lorem ipsum Ullamco quis ut Free▼
</div>

---

.justify {
  text-align: justify;
}
.justify:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what exactly is a Free▼?

Comment: @Tom i wager it represents a drop-down menu of Free things as menu items

Comment: @aequalsb Oh, that would make sense. Thanks.

Comment: @aequalsb Good guess, you are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap them in a span with `display: inline-block` and `text-align` them as needed (right or left)

http://jsfiddle.net/806hjj7a/1/

Comment: That's a good workaround but do you know why Chrome does break it?

Comment: @Kaiido subjectivity is my best response to that -- but it is clearly a difference of method. Chrome is seeing the `&#9660;` as a distinct "word".

Comment: @aequalsb I don't trust subjectivity about things like that, utf-8 have rules, I wonder why Chrome have this behaviour, when other softwares like e.g TextEdit don't.

Comment: @Explosion nice elegant result, because adding a `&nbsp;` didn't affect it. also, my fiddle shows the `text-align:left` is not needed. http://jsfiddle.net/aequalsb/9kgeocca/

Comment: @Kalido utf-8 would not designate rules for discerning `&#9660;` as a separate "word" leaving it up to the programmers subjective logic